# OpenCV cannot connect to video stream - lack of some codec?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I use application *IPCamera* on my mobile phone with Android to output (share) video image from it's camera to LAN. I can access it on PC browser - that is ok.

However, I want to make OpenCV capture this video stream from IP address by typing

```
VideoCapture cap("http://admin:admin@192.168.0.11:8081/?action=stream?dummy=param.mjpg");
 while( cap.isOpened() )
 {
    Mat frame;
    if ( ! cap.read(frame) )
        break;

    cout << "Connected!!";

    imshow("lalala",frame);
    int k = waitKey(10);
    if ( k==27 )
        break;
}
```

and i got error:

[image]

Actual codec, which is used by phone is **mjpeg** (i read it from application on my mobile). I don't know if OpenCV supports this, but is that about mobile application uses some kind of unique codec, or my PC lacks it, or maybe C++/OpenCV code is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On PC opencv can capture your video stream from your mobile prone.. 
Like. You are using right connection string, like this for rtsp stream in my case.

```
VideoCapture capture("rtsp://USER:PASS@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/axis-media/media.amp?camera=2");
```

Probably, You don't have FFMPEG instaled corectly. You need to reinstall Opencv. First you need to install FFMPEG and Opencv After that.
In opencv 3.0.0 and 3.1 try to add

```
#include <opencv2\videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp>
```

Some tips how to install ffmpeg and sample in C++ on linux debian Here [Code and tips and tricks](http://funvision.blogspot.com/2015/11/opencv-300-videocapture-file-web-camera.html)